# print variable lines between 2 matched characters

Tags: shell, awk, sed

```
cat massive_data.txt
Will
12
123
1234
12345
/>

Liu
23
34
/>

Will
1234
12345
/>

Will
1234
12345
.
.
.
```

In the above text, I want fetch the line between every "Will"
 and "/>", ignore the others.But the number of the gap line is variable,
I used the below command but got inaccurate result

```
sed -n '/\<Sector/,/\/\>/p' massive_data.txt
Will
12
123
1234
12345
/>

Will
1234
12345
/>

Will
1234
12345
.
.
.
```

How can I use "sed" or "awk" to solve the problem?
I expect result is as below:

```
Will
12
123
1234
12345
/>

Will
1234
12345
/>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Why isn't the last `Will` starting block printed? Cause it does not end in `/>`?  How does it end? `...` isn't really helpful.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I need the data contain "Will" and "/>", ... means still a lot of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '$1 == "Will"{p=1} p{data = data $0 RS} $1 == "/>"{print data; p=0; data=""}' file
```

```
Will
12
123
1234
12345
/>


Will
1234
12345
/>
```

**Explanation:**

- `$1 == "Will"{p=1}`: Set flag `p=1` when first column is "Will"
- `p{data = data $0 RS}`: If `p==1` then keep appending each line into a variable `data`
- `$1 == "/>"{print data; p=0; data=""`: If first column is `/>` then print `data` and reset `p` and `data` variables.

---

If there is a blank line after `/>` then you can use `awk` like this also:

```
awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= '/^Will/ && /\/>$/' file
```

Comment: thanks a lot, sir, I was wondering if you could explain what's mean 
     {p=1} p{data = data $0 RS}
  in your first code?

Comment: I've added explanation in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, sir, in the below command:
     awk -v ORS='\n\n' -v RS= '/^Will/ && /\/>$/' file
is the "-v" means mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}/^Will/&&/\/>/' file
Will
12
123
1234
12345
/>
Will
1234
12345
/>
```

Empty `RS` splits record at an empty line. Script prints records that start with `Will` and end in `/>`.

Comment: If you want the empty lines after each record add `{print $0 ORS}` after the regex.

Comment: thanks a lot,sir, I try your way and get expect result, could you explain the why the "RS" splits record is empty and what's the mean of "&&" in your code, is it mean " AND" ?

Comment: By default a record in awk is a newline (`\n`) terminated string. You can change that behaviour by setting variable `RS` to whatever you desire to mark the end of a record. `RS=""` sets the end of a record to an empty line (or lines) so basically with this data a record is: `Will.../>\n\n`. And `&&` is AND.

Answer (score 0):

based on what I understood :

cat  filename | sed -n '/Will/,/>/p' | grep -v "/>"

Output :

```
Will
12
123
1234
12345
Will
1234
12345
Will
1234
12345
```